# How to run 127.0.0.1 with port 127.0.0.1:8000 on .httaccess?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, next.js

How to run sub domain with nodejs running port 127.0.0.1:8000 ?

.httaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/ [P,L]
RewriteCpnd %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8000/$1 [P,L]
```

But I get error **`Internal Server Error`**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a typo on the third line of your `.htaccess` - `RewriteCpnd` should actually be `RewriteCond`.

You may find it helpful to use a [.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) in future.